# Accessing Java object-graphs

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am trying to find the access pattern of objects in some Java benchmark applications. To be more precise, what I want is to be able to know what part of an object was accessed and when.

For example, if an application has two objects, say `a` and `b` of types `A` and `B`(a fairly non-realistic assumption :P), but still!

Now A looks like this

```
A{
 int x;
 String y;
 B haha;
}

B{
 int w;
 ArrayList<Integer> someCollection;
}
```

Now if the application makes an access directly or indirectly via some function or whatever, then I want to track these accesses down to the finest level (for example in case of that `someCollection` if I add an element some object (primitive or complex) depending on the class will change.

Then the information I am looking for is that I will know what object/sub-object was `read/written`.

In order all the access to every objects (if possible to the finest level)
AFIK Java stores the object as object-graphs (graphs of objects where the parent object has the subobjects as its children) for garbage collection. Is there any instrumentation framework/tool that can help me access these object-graphs or whatever data-structure the JVM uses? I believe (though not sure) that if I can access these graphs I will be able to achieve what I am trying to do!

Comment: Smells like a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What larger problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: @MattBall I added detail about what exactly my goal is. Hope this makes it more clear (and hopefully does not confuse you more :P)